# create new customer attribute in magento admin panel

Tags: magento-1.8, admin-panel, customer-attribute

I'm creating new customer attribute in magento admin panel but it's returning an **error Text length does not satisfy specified text range.**

the attribute code is **mag_customer_testing_id**, the attribute code length is accepting less than 21.

how can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is enterprise edition or customer attributes extension?  Or do you mean CUSTOM attribute?

Comment: @Amasty, Enterprise Edition, yes custom attribute

Answer (score 1):

So the reason for this is because:

> customer attribute code can have prefix "customer_" and its length must be max length minus prefix length

Now the code for the limit can be found at `app/code/core/Enterprise/Customer/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Main.php` where it uses the constant `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute::ATTRIBUTE_CODE_MAX_LENGTH`

So it appears that normally a EAV attribute has a limit of 30 characts, so product and customer. As to why this limit is in place I am sorry but I dont know. The table seems to allow 255, maybe someone else can tell you why.

There are some thoughts behind this limit [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/7491/158)